# How can I get this title centered on top of this container?

Tags: html, css

I found this code on codepen and was trying some stuff with it. I tried to centered the title on top of it but it won't let me do it. What's wrong with it ?

What could I do ?

Here's a screenshot of the issue : [image: issue]

Here's my code :

```css
.container {
    background: transparent;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 30vmin;
    overflow: hidden;
    transform: skew(5deg);
}

.container .card {
    border: none;
    background: transparent;
    flex: 1;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    height: 60vmin;
    position: relative;
}

.container .card .card__head {
    border-radius: 15px;
    color: black;
    background: rgba(255, 30, 173, 0.75);
    padding: 0.5em;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    min-width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    font-size: 1em;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.container .card:hover {
    flex-grow: 10;
}

.container .card:hover img {
    filter: grayscale(0);
}

.container .card:hover .card__head {
    text-align: center;
    top: calc(100% - 2em);
    color: white;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    font-size: 2em;
    transform: rotate(0deg) skew(-5deg);
}

.container .card img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    filter: grayscale(100%);
}

.container .card:not(:nth-child(5)) {
    background: transparent;
    margin-right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2>PROCHAINEMENT</h2>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d6/Cat_plotting_something_evil%21.jpg">
    <div class="card__head">Plotting Cat</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d8/False_alarm_-a.jpg/1280px-False_alarm_-a.jpg">
    <div class="card__head">Angry Cat</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/83/Neugierige-Katze.JPG/1280px-Neugierige-Katze.JPG">
    <div class="card__head">Curious Cat</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/75/Al_acecho_%289272124788%29.jpg/1280px-Al_acecho_%289272124788%29.jpg">
    <div class="card__head">Prowling Cat</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/de/Mimi%26Tigsi.jpg/1280px-Mimi%26Tigsi.jpg">
    <div class="card__head">Sleepy Cat</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using absolute positioning can sacrifice positioning when resizing the browser or the screen. In a solution without absolute positioning, you can put the `<h2>` outside of the container. Also, the container has a `margin: 30vmin;`. You can separate that top spacing by removing the top margin. Here I set `margin-top: 0; !important;` to get rid of that spacing. Then I used `text-align: center;` to position the `h2` text in the center.

```css
.container {
    background: transparent;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 30vmin;
    margin-top: 0 !important;
    overflow: hidden;
    transform: skew(5deg);
}

.container .card {
    border: none;
    background: transparent;
    flex: 1;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    height: 60vmin;
    position: relative;
}

.container .card .card__head {
    border-radius: 15px;
    color: black;
    background: rgba(255, 30, 173, 0.75);
    padding: 0.5em;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    min-width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    font-size: 1em;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.container .card:hover {
    flex-grow: 10;
}

.container .card:hover img {
    filter: grayscale(0);
}

.container .card:hover .card__head {
    text-align: center;
    top: calc(100% - 2em);
    color: white;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    font-size: 2em;
    transform: rotate(0deg) skew(-5deg);
}

.container .card img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    filter: grayscale(100%);
}

.container .card:not(:nth-child(5)) {
    background: transparent;
    margin-right: 1em;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h2>PROCHAINEMENT</h2>
<div class="container">
  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d6/Cat_plotting_something_evil%21.jpg">
    <div class="card__head">Plotting Cat</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d8/False_alarm_-a.jpg/1280px-False_alarm_-a.jpg">
    <div class="card__head">Angry Cat</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/83/Neugierige-Katze.JPG/1280px-Neugierige-Katze.JPG">
    <div class="card__head">Curious Cat</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/75/Al_acecho_%289272124788%29.jpg/1280px-Al_acecho_%289272124788%29.jpg">
    <div class="card__head">Prowling Cat</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/de/Mimi%26Tigsi.jpg/1280px-Mimi%26Tigsi.jpg">
    <div class="card__head">Sleepy Cat</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this :

```css
.container {
    background: transparent;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin:30vmin;
    transform: skew(5deg);
}
.container h2
{
    position:absolute;
    top:-70px;
}

.container .card {
    border: none;
    background: transparent;
    flex: 1;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    height: 60vmin;
    position: relative;
}

.container .card .card__head {
    border-radius: 15px;
    color: black;
    background: rgba(255, 30, 173, 0.75);
    padding: 0.5em;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    min-width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    font-size: 1em;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.container .card:hover {
    flex-grow: 10;
}

.container .card:hover img {
    filter: grayscale(0);
}

.container .card:hover .card__head {
    text-align: center;
    top: calc(100% - 2em);
    color: white;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    font-size: 2em;
    transform: rotate(0deg) skew(-5deg);
}

.container .card img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    filter: grayscale(100%);
}

.container .card:not(:nth-child(5)) {
    background: transparent;
    margin-right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <h2>PROCHAINEMENT</h2>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d6/Cat_plotting_something_evil%21.jpg">
    <div class="card__head">Plotting Cat</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d8/False_alarm_-a.jpg/1280px-False_alarm_-a.jpg">
    <div class="card__head">Angry Cat</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/83/Neugierige-Katze.JPG/1280px-Neugierige-Katze.JPG">
    <div class="card__head">Curious Cat</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/75/Al_acecho_%289272124788%29.jpg/1280px-Al_acecho_%289272124788%29.jpg">
    <div class="card__head">Prowling Cat</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/de/Mimi%26Tigsi.jpg/1280px-Mimi%26Tigsi.jpg">
    <div class="card__head">Sleepy Cat</div>
  </div>
```